# How to convert from UTF-16 array to UTF-8 string?

Tags: arrays, unicode, encoding, glib, vala

I have a situation where I receive UTF-16 codepoints (one at a time). So I'm collecting them in a list and later convert the list to an array.

That leaves me with a `uint16[]`, but `GLib.convert ()` needs a string instead:

```cs
int main () {
    var utf16data = new Gee.ArrayList<uint16> ();

    utf16data.add ('A');
    utf16data.add (0xD83C);
    utf16data.add (0xDC1C);

    var utf16array = utf16data.to_array ();

    try {
        // convert expects a string here
        var s = convert (utf16array, utf16data.size * 2, "UTF-8", "UTF-16LE");
        stdout.printf ("%s\n", s);
    } 
    catch (ConvertError e) {
        stderr.printf (@"error: $(e.message)\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So how do I convert a UTF-16 array into a UTF-8 string?

**Update**:

I tried to just cast the array:

```cs
int main () {
    var utf16data = new Gee.ArrayList<uint16> ();

    utf16data.add ('A');
    utf16data.add (0xD83C);
    utf16data.add (0xDC1C);
    // utf16data.add (0);

    var utf16array = utf16data.to_array ();

    try {
        size_t bytes_read;
        size_t bytes_written;
        var s = convert ((string) utf16array, utf16data.size * 2, "UTF-8", "UTF-16LE", out bytes_read, out bytes_written);
        stdout.puts (@"bytes_read = $bytes_read\n");
        stdout.puts (@"bytes_written = $bytes_written\n");
        stdout.puts (@"s.length = $(s.length)\n");
        // Should print "A", but the Unicode symbol is not printed
        stdout.puts (@"s = $s\n");
    } 
    catch (ConvertError e) {
        stderr.printf (@"error: $(e.message)\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now at least the "A" is written to stdout, but the Unicode symbol is not.

```
bytes_read = 6
bytes_written = 3
s.length = 1
s = A
```

Is it correct to just cast an array to a string in this context?

Why is the Unicode symbol not converted?

**Update 2**:

This is the code that I have now settled with:

```cs
int main () {
    var utf16data = new Gee.ArrayList<uint16> ();

    utf16data.add ('A');
    utf16data.add (0xD83C);
    utf16data.add (0xDC1C);

    // Replacement for 
    // utf16array = utf16data.to_array;
    uint16[] utf16array = new uint16[utf16data.size];
    for (int i = 0; i < utf16data.size; i++)
        utf16array[i] = utf16data[i];

    try {
        var s = convert ((string)utf16array, utf16array.length * 2, "UTF-8", "UTF-16LE");
        stdout.puts (@"$s\n");
    } 
    catch (ConvertError e) {
        stderr.puts (@"error: $(e.message)\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the values are *bytes*, and not something like *characters*? (Which, given Java's string handling, may possibly be stored 'conveniently', rather than as literal bytes. Disclaimer: this -> · <- is the full extent of my Java knowledge.) Also, your 2 Unicode characters are well within the High Surrogate Range (meaning the *two* codes ought to represent one *character*. Does it work with an easier glyph?

Comment: @Jongware The utf16data array is fine, I think my cast breaks everything here. It doesn't even work with a 'A', 'B', 'C' input. I have to figure out how to put the UTF-16 data into the `convert ()` method. It's Vala not Java, btw. (different languages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `to_array`. It does not produce an array of `uint16`, but an array to pointers, with the value set to the `uint16` value. This is the standard boxed representations. There seems to be a problem in Gee that it isn't producing an array of the correct type. If you change the array to:

```
uint16[] utf16array = {'A', 0xD83C, 0xDC1C};
```

It works just fine.

Comment: Any idea how to dynamically add values though? I just tried `GLib.Array<uint32>` that doesn't work either.

Comment: Ok, I'm no using a simple loop which is not efficient, but it works (see my update of the question).

Comment: You can dynamically expand an array in Vala using `+=` so long as it is either a local variable or a private field.